# Semi-direct product and crossed product symbols

Tags: formatting, symbols, built-in-symbols, custom-notation, notation

Does Mathematica have any symbols for the semi-direct product $\rtimes$ (or $\ltimes$) and the crossed product $\bowtie$? I have looked at the lists containing all symbols and couldn't find it there. Interestingly the term `SemidirectProduct` is mentioned on the page of FiniteGroupData as a special group specification but even there the description uses the symbol `\:f0e3` which looks like a small minus sign...

If they really aren't part of the system, is there any way to implement such symbols? (Without any properties a priori, just as if they were letters or relation symbols that have no meaning attached to them)

This would be really great for working with finite groups and typesetting group names.

Comment: I think this computer algebra system software [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/639#7118) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) to create an alias for a new operator:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAliases, "sdp"}] = TemplateBox[
    {},
    "SemidirectProduct",
    DisplayFunction -> ("⋊"&),
    InterpretationFunction :> (Sequence["~", "SemidirectProduct", "~"]&),
    SyntaxForm -> "*"
];
```

Then use <kbd>Escape</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>Escape</kbd> to enter the operator:

```
a ⋊ b
```

> SemidirectProduct[a, b]

Answer (score 0):

One way to enter the semi-direct product symbol (LaTex \rtimes) is to place its Unicode value 22CA into the front-end function FromCaracterCode[]. The code should be prefixed with "\:" as in FromCaracterCode[\:22CA].

```
FromCharacterCode[⋊]
```